# Solution for e-Forms engine

Tags: forms, validation, webforms

My client is asking for a solution that handles e-forms generation to be done by a technology-savvy user (not a developer). In other words,  An e-form engine for dynamic creation and implementation of electronic forms.

Is there any tool/solution in the market available that handles this requirement? I would love to avoid building it from scratch.

Comment: I found a good solution fits with my requirement and thought to share it with you. It is called Frevvo. www.frevvo.com

Answer (score 1):

What's the domain? What happens to the form - email / db save? What kind of forms - are they surveys, invoices, etc.  Are pdfs that a user fills out and then submits (which saves the data somewhere) good enough?  Is there supposed to be a user authentication piece?

I think you'll get better responses with a bit more info.

---

Edit:
I use [Google Survey](https://drive.googleblog.com/2008/02/stop-sharing-spreadsheets-start.html) when I need to put together a quick and dirty data collection piece.  It's pretty good at what it does.  I've used it to collect roster information and game availability from my soccer team.  Depending on who your end users are, and what kind of experience you want them to have, it may work out.  It's stupid simple.

Comment: Forms results to be stored in the database. They can be anything that lies under the category "simple forms" with maybe simple validation. They prefer it is web form other than PDF filling,unless they store in the database. Authentication is not part of the scope.